# How to use same dataset for multiple report?

Tags: dataset, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

Is there a way to use the same dataset for multiple Power BI report.

Let's assume I have excel data source, I will have it imported into Power BI service account as part of report publish. Now I'm creating one more report with the same data source, but this time it creates a new dataset in service account.

How do I can use the same dataset for both of the Power BI report available in same workspace (or) in the different workspace?

Comment: By creating a live connection to Power BI service `Get Data\Power Bi Datasets`

Comment: I may need to publish a report along with dataset since I didn't provide with server machine to get live connection to Power BI Service account. I have already published 1 report with the dataset, now I need to use the same dataset for another report as well.

Comment: Server machine?  You don't need a server machine for that. You publish a report along with its dataset, then create a new one, but instead of importing excel files you connect to the already published into Power Bi service dataset. Performance might suffer a little bit, though.`Get Data\Power Bi Datasets` choose a dataset you want to connect to and that's it. [Find out more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-report-lifecycle-datasets#targetText=To%20establish%20a%20connection%20to,then%20select%20Power%20BI%20datasets.)

Comment: Yes got it, Thank you... Actually, I can get an option for *Power BI Datasets* under **Get Data\Power BI\Power BI datasets**

Comment: Yes, the full path to the **Power BI datasets** depends on the PBI version. In the latest one, **Power BI datasets** can be found under **Power Platform**. In earlier ones, it might be **Power BI** or **Online Services** or something else. I usually use search.

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable comments... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look into using Power BI Dataflows, or you can use the Shared Datasets which is in preview now.

[Power BI Dataflows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-dataflows-create-use)

[Shared Datasets (Preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-datasets-across-workspaces)

When connecting to these data sets from Power BI Desktop, either choose:

*Get Data -> Power BI datasets*

or

*Get Data -> Power BI dataflows*

Comment: Thank you... I have got the option for *Power BI Datasets* under **Get Data\Power BI\Power BI datasets**... :)

Answer (score 1):

In the query designer you can add a blank query and refer to the importet table. Lets assume the importet table name is `Imported Table`. Add a blank query:

[image]

Write in the expression the table name:

[image]

Now you have a copy of your `Imported Table`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, But I have my report in the different project files. In that case, *Get Data -> Power BI datasets* works fine for me. Wishes for your effort...